# (New to Python) Keep getting a "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm extremely new to Python and I'm trying to write a program for a GUI to pull the most and least frequent name occurrences from a list for a class assignment. I keep getting a

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

error on this code, and I know it has to do with the line:

```
word_frequencies += float[self.listMyData.Count(word)]/len[self.listMyData]
```

But I'm not sure exactly what the error is saying. I looked at similar questions on here but still wasn't sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code in full:

```
import wx
import myLoopGUI

class MyLoopFrame(myLoopGUI.MyFrame1):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        myLoopGUI.MyFrame1.__init__(self, parent)

    def clkAddData(self,parent):
        if len(self.txtAddData.Value) != 0:
            try:
                myname = str(self.txtAddData.Value)
                self.listMyData.Append(str(myname))
            except:
                wx.MessageBox("This has to be a name!")            
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("This can't be empty")




    def clkFindMost(self, parent):
        unique_words = []
        for word in range(self.listMyData.GetCount()):
                if word not in unique_words:
                    unique_words += [word]
        word_frequencies = []
        for word in unique_words:
            word_frequencies += float[self.listMyData.Count(word)]/len[self.listMyData]  

        max_index = 0
        frequent_words =[]
        for i in range(len(unique_words)):
            if word_frequencies[i] >= word_frequencies[max_index]:
                max_index = i
                frequent_words += unique_words[max_index]
        self.txtResults.Value = frequent_words



myApp = wx.App(False)
myFrame = MyLoopFrame(None)
myFrame.Show()
myApp.MainLoop()
```

Comment: what is "listMyData"?

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow what's going on if we don't know what any of the methods and properties do/are. Please put together an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem in a self-contained way.

Comment: Sorry. listMyData is an event that corresponds to a text box in the GUI. I'm using wxFormBuilder to create an interface where you plug numbers into a list box and then click one of two buttons to either find the most frequent name or the least frequent name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Count` is a property of `myListData`. You put parentheses "`()`" behind it, like if it were a function, but it isn't. It's just a set integer value. That would be like doing this:

```
y = 5
x = y(word)
```

Which doesn't make sense. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `word` and `myListData.Count`, but maybe what you're looking for is `self.myListData[word].Count`.

[As user3666197 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26133019), you also want to change the `float[...]` to `float(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

[omni has explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26132950) the `.Count` property issue.

You also might want to revise the line **`word_frequencies += float[ ...`** due to this:

```
>>> float[ 5 ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>> float( 5 )
5.0
>>>
```